# Selenium WebDriver C# always unable to find anything on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

i wrote a simple automated test with visual studio 2012 C# and selenium WebDriver.
It works fine on Google Chrome (it is only a little slow).
My code has to works also on Internet Explorer..but..selenium web driver is always unable to find any web element..only if i search it by id, css, xpath, name..

i thought that was my code.. but if i try to do a simple search on google i have the same problem.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Environment;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
    IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Users\IEDriverServerpath\IEDriverServer.exe", options);
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

 driver.FindElement(By.Id("q")).SendKeys("WebDriver");
```

Chrome goes on google.com and sends "WebDriver" in the search box..
IE goes on google but visual studio "explodes" on "obsolete element" error.. "unable to find element with id == q" (also with xpath)

i'm forgetting some settings for IE?

UPDATE

Set correctly IEDriverServer in PATH and it worked..Sorry i'm a rookie..

Comment: in order to make work correctly webdriver with IE on windows, IEDriverServer.exe location has to be set in the PATH Environment Variable.

Comment: oh! as i wrote in the question, i am a selenium noob. i'm doing some pratice with it (for example learning about Page Factory) but i'm still a noob. i'll study it